# Magento 2.3 How to show Out of Stock Products only in Search?

Tags: magento2.3, catalog, catalogsearch, out-of-stock, layer

My site is supposed to show out of stock products in some places in the catalogue, so the Catalog > Inventory > Display Out of Stock Products setting is set to "Yes."
But I do not want out of stock products to show up in the search. Before upgrading to M2.3, we accomplished this by overriding \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Plugin\Layer's  beforePrepareProductCollection() function:

```
 public function beforePrepareProductCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection $collection
    ) {

        $_category = $subject->getCurrentCategory();
        if (is_object($_category) and in_array($_category->getId(), array(161, 184)))// don't apply to Recently Sold, Our Archive categories
        {
            return;
        }

        parent::beforePrepareProductCollection($subject, $collection);
        $stockFlag = 'has_stock_status_filter';
        if (!$collection->hasFlag($stockFlag)) {
            $resource = $this->getStockStatusResource();
            $resource->addStockDataToCollection(
                $collection,
                true // force
            );
            $collection->setFlag($stockFlag, true);
        }
    }

    protected function getStockStatusResource()
    {
        if (empty($this->stockStatusResource)) {
            $this->stockStatusResource = $this->stockStatusFactory->create();
        }
        return $this->stockStatusResource;
    }
```

Now that Layer.php is gone in Magento 2.3, I don't know where to start with trying to hide out of stock products in search. I thought maybe I could use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Plugin\ProductSearch, but that isn't used at all as far as I can tell.

Comment: Setting the visibility in the product to only catalog will fulfill your need I guess.

Comment: Hoping for an automated solution; we have a lot of products.

Comment: You can update them via import export https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-2-product-import-export.html

Comment: Even with the import/export, this would still need to be done manually each time a product is purchased, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding the Layer plugin directly to my module Wfx_Stock which previously extended Layer.php

in di.xml:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
        <plugin name="addStockStatusOnPrepareFrontCollection" type="Wfx\Stock\Model\Plugin\Layer" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Then in app\code\Wfx\Stock\Model\Plugin\Layer.php

```
<?php
namespace Wfx\Stock\Model\Plugin;

class Layer
{

    /**
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param StatusFactory $stockStatusFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock $stockHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\StatusFactory $stockStatusFactory
    ) {
        $this->stockStatusFactory  = $stockStatusFactory;
        $this->stockHelper = $stockHelper;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Before prepare product collection handler
     *  - Hide out of stock products in search, unless in "Recently Sold" or Our Archive
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection $collection
     *
     * @return void
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function beforePrepareProductCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection $collection
    ) {
        $_category = $subject->getCurrentCategory();
        if (is_object($_category) and in_array($_category->getId(), array(161, 184)))// Recently Sold, Our Archive
        {
            return;
        }
        
        $stockFlag = 'has_stock_status_filter';
        if (!$collection->hasFlag($stockFlag)) {
            $resource = $this->getStockStatusResource();
            $resource->addStockDataToCollection(
                $collection,
                true // force
            );
            $collection->setFlag($stockFlag, true);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Get config value for 'display out of stock' option
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isEnabledShowOutOfStock()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'cataloginventory/options/show_out_of_stock',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return Status
     */
    protected function getStockStatusResource()
    {
        if (empty($this->stockStatusResource)) {
            $this->stockStatusResource = $this->stockStatusFactory->create();
        }
        return $this->stockStatusResource;
    }

}
```